# Awaiting a callback with async functions

Tags: javascript

I want to enable code calling this async function to wait for the express server to be running before continuing.

I don't think it is enough to do the following because `app.listen` does not return a promise.

```
async function boot(app) {
    await app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Running on ${port}`);
    });
}
```

Do I need to promisify the call to `app.listen`?

```
async function boot(app) {
    await new Promise(resolve => app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Running on ${port}`);
        resolve();
    }));
}
```

Comment: Yes. Async/await are just a wrapper around promises.  In the first example, `await` has no idea what you're asking it to wait for.

Comment: Is there a better/terser/more idiomatic way than my promisified version?

Comment: I prefer having the promisification in a separate method (i.e., `app.listenAsync`), which keeps all of your app logic using `async`/`await`.

Comment: Good call! Thanks